# Android error!! relating to "Gradle build finished with 1 error"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zhuxi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I try to create a new project, the same problem occured...
Any one can help?

Exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34) at 
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236) at 
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228) at 
org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169) at 
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106) at 
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61) at 
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228) at 
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215) at 
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77) at 
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58) at 
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32) at 
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113) at 
org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37) at 
org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37) at 
org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23) at 
org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43) at 
org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32) at 
org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37) at 
org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30) at 
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196) at 
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193) at 
org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169) at 
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106) at 
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56) at 
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193) at 
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119) at 
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102) at 
org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50) at 
org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40) at 
org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169) at 
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106) at 
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75) at 
org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35) at 
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41) at 
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44) at 
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72) at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50) at 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297) at 
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54) at 
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt at 
com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:201) at 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82) at 
org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95) at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76) ... 78 more Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt at 
com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:867) at 
com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:194) ... 85 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\zhuxi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\zhuxi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\manifests\instant-run\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \?\C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.zhuxi.myapplication -0 apk --preferred-density xhdpi --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors} at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116) at
com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:865) ... 86 more Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\zhuxi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\zhuxi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\manifests\instant-run\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \?\C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.zhuxi.myapplication -0 apk --preferred-density xhdpi --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\zhuxi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors} at 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74) at 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49) at 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78) at 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53) at 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60) Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\zhuxi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741502 at 
org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369) at 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47) ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please run it with --stacktrace and paste here the stack trace
We need your log to help you.

Comment: Hi, can you try disabling Instant Run and then try again to run?